# How to pass props through Route to Component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a header component with some links, when Test page is loaded after clicking a link I want to pass it a prop (it's value will come from state in the header page). The aim is that the Test page will automatically update when the Header page state is updated.

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div>        
            <Route exact path="/test" render={(props) => <Test {...props} myprop={"abc"} /> } />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Header.js:

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Link to="/test">
            Test Page
          </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I know you can easily pass props from a route as per my code above ie. myprop will be available in the Test page, but I want to set myprop dynamically from the Header somehow (maybe Link is the wrong mechanism?) so that it will be aware of changes and do the refresh automatically - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold the prop in your App component's state, and then pass it down to both the Header and the Test props. And the Header also receives the setState function, to be able to modify it. Here's what I'm imagining it like:

```
function App(){    
  let [someProp, setSomeProp] = useState();
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header prop={someProp} setProp={setSomeProp}/>
        <div>        
            <Route exact path="/test" render={(props) => <Test {...props} myprop={someProp} /> } />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this works for you. Using functional components instead of class components has been more popular since the addition of hooks to functional components last year.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this working using your suggestion.